# how to get value of a field in fields_view_get?

Tags: odoo

I want to get a value of a field in fields_view_get method in openerp 7.0.

I tried the following:
1- send the value of the field in the context attribute as following:

```
< field name="employee_id" context="{'employee_id':employee_id}" />
```

and in the fields_view_get I get it as following:

```
print "employee_id in the context value is  %s"%(context.get('employee_id', False))
```

but it always the the context.get(...) returns False. so I tried the following:

2- on the onchange method of the field I send the value of the field in the context as following:

```
def onchange_employee_id(self, cr, uid, ids, employee_id):
return {'context': {'employee_id': employee_id}}
```

and in the fields_view_get I get it as following:

```
print "employee_id in the context value is  %s"%(context.get('employee_id', False))
```

but also the same thing always the context.get(..) returns False.

How can I get the value of a field in fields_view_get function ?

Comment: please specify the object to which employee_id belongs?

Comment: @Baiju KS: thanks for your reply.
I use the employee_id in a custom object called 'Travel'.

Comment: try this code in onchange_employee_id:  return {'value': {'employee_id': employee_id}}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer is too late for you, but perhaps someone will find it useful.

If you need the dynamic view just on form view, you should write a tree view and you can put the selected record id to the context...so with the context id, you can read the fields.

But fields_view_get is not too easy. Dont forget about update the return dictionary (the two very important keys: fields, arch).
If you want to use invisible or readonly tag, you should use modifiers tag like attrs.

Example:

```
def fields_view_get(self, cr, uid, view_id=False, view_type='tree', context=None, toolbar=False, submenu=False):
    fields = self.read(cr, uid, context['working_id'], [])
    actualView = super(ModelName, self).fields_view_get(cr, uid, view_id, view_type, context, toolbar, submenu)

    # you can write default view in xml and dynamic complete with some field in this method
    actualView['fields'].update({'field_name':{'type': 'text', 'string': 'Name'}})
    arch = minidom.parseString(actualView['arch'])

    #for example: triggered to <newline/> field 
    newlineField = arch.getElementByTagName('newline').item(0) 
    element = arch.createElement('field_name')
    element.setAttribute('name', 'Name')
    newlineField.insertBefore(element, 0)

    actualView['arch'] = arch.toxml("utf-8")
    return actualView
```